# Animate an element to move between 2 elements in a dynamically created curved path

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, curves

I've been trying to do this for a project and i failed on every try. The image says it all.
The idea is to create a script to:
Select Start Point and Ending Point elements.
Move "bee" between this 2 elements in a certain time when the function is called.

I can't post images :/ 
here's the link
http://i59.tinypic.com/swakav.png

Comment: If you are working with jQuery you might wanna have a look at crSpline - http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html

Comment: Hey @Syd, thanks for the comment! I don't think it could fit a responsive website, i've been checking  it and the way it was written it would be easier to do from 0, but i have no idea on how to do it  :o